# Image Module Python

Tags: python

I'm getting an error about a module and have searched for a solution for some time now and have come up empty handed. I'm coding in python and working in eclipse pydev. At the top of my code I typed.

```
import Image
```

I get a error that states `ImportError: No module named Image`

Here is just some screenshots of the Python Interpreter System Pythonpath

http://imageshack.us/a/img5/614/92989360.png

http://imageshack.us/f/545/79985417.png/

Comment: Do you have **PIL** installed? Or whatever package you expect `Image` module to come from?

Comment: i think it should be `from PIL import Image`

Comment: Yes i tried that exact line and It then said No module named Pil right know i guess im trying to install pil and see how it turns out

Comment: @avasal no, it's just `import Image`.  But it needs to be installed, of course..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the Python Image Libray:

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

You can install it using pip via:

```
pip install PIL
```

Comment: Hi @Michael Place :-
While entering using "pip install PIL" i'm getting below error.
**Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL**

I'm using Jupyter Notebook version:- 3.6.5